# How to edit Selection indicator in UIPicker?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

[image: https://www.cocoatreeapplications.com/images/reboursScreenshot.png]
Ad you can see, there is a example. The UI picker's Selection indicator. How can I do the similar thing on my Apps?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a feature of UIPickerView in the disclosed API. The screenshot you show is either drawing the "hrs", "min", "sec" labels itself or is using an undisclosed API (possibly overriding the _UIPickerViewSelectionBar).

It would be pretty easy to draw labels like this yourself. Just get the UIPickerView and add the UILabels over the top of the UIPickerView after it has loaded.